# Internal hyperlinks in a MMS

Tags: hyperlink, wap, mms, wml

Is it possible to put an internal hypertext link (or anchor) inside a MMS. I wan't to offer a user of a MMS service to choose between several links and make his way inside the MMS. 
Any idea how it is possible ?

Answer (score 3):

how are you composing your MMS? are you using some kind of API or gateway message compiler? or creating the message from scratch (multipart MIME)?

I believe the default mimetype in MMS is WAP/WML (possibly application/vnd.wap.mms-message ?) in which case you can construct your page as series of cards. i.e. something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE wml PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml_1.1.xml">

<wml>

<card id="part1" title="Intro">
<p>
<go href="#part3">click to go to card 3</go>
</p>
</card>

<card id="part2" title="And More">
<p>
blah blah blah
</p>
</card>

<card id="part3" title="Target Page">
<p>
blah blah blah
</p>
</card>

</wml>
```

w3schools have [a good tutorial on wml](https://web.archive.org/web/20101201115125/http://w3schools.com/wap/wap_intro.asp)