# How to put a hyperlink into an MMS message?

Tags: php, email, sms, mms

What language is used to insert hyperlinks into an MMS message?

I'm sending MMS messages to my cellphone, from my computer, but don't know how to include a link.

I'm using php to send emails to the MMS service.  Images and plain text show up just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368348/internal-hyperlinks-in-a-mms

Comment: Off topic: what MMS service do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just include the link in plaintext.  However, there is another way detailed here:

http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?193656-Invoking-Browser-from-MMS