# Is it possible to create an MMS which contains a url link to launch a local app

Tags: ios, mms, url-scheme

I can launch my app if I embed a url in an SMS and then the user clicks on the url from within the message app. I have this all working.

What I would like to be able to do however is send an MMS to the device which contains a number of image(s) and text filling the screen and when the user clicks on the url within the MMS my app is launched same as it is if clicked from within an SMS.

Is it possible to mock this up so I can see it working? i.e. how could I create an MMS containing a working active link to demo a proof of concept (I'm not talking about creating an MMS programatically on iOS, just how to create one containing my app's url to send to the device)?

Comment: If you already have URL schemes working in your app, and just need to know how to add a link to an MMS on iOS, you can try asking this question over at [apple.SE](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** This answer was written under the assumption that implementation details were required for the URL handling part. I'll leave the technical details here for future Googlers.

[Here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/39754-sending-mms.html) is a link to a forum thread which seems to indicate you can't send MMSes from the iPhone programmatically (I know you said you didn't want to know this anyway, but it's here for completeness). The suggestion is to use a message provider's MMS gateway directly (e.g http://www.smsglobal.com).

Instructions on how to get a hyperlink into an MMS are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264118/how-to-put-a-hyperlink-into-an-mms-message). You can just write it in plain text, or use an anchor: <a href="myapp://"> Not 100% sure the iPhone will properly parse those anchor tags in an MMS though.

---

Read [this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) article. The gist is that you add a "URL types" row to your Info.plist and set it to any valid protocol, say `myapp`, and then a user opens a link in an MMS to a `myapp` URL. Article excerpt:

> ```
> myapp://
> myapp://some/path/here
> myapp://?foo=1&amp;bar=2
> myapp://some/path/here?foo=1&amp;bar=2
> ```
>
> The iPhone SDK, when launching the application in response to any of the URLs above, will send a message to the UIApplicationDelegate.
>
> If you want to provide a custom handler, simply provide an implementation for the message in your delegate. For example:
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
> {
>   // Do something with the url here
> }
> ```

Comment: According to the question, the OP has url-scheme handling in place already - well, that is if I understood everything correctly.

Comment: Yes Till that is correct. I would like to a) check its possible on iOS b)create an MMS containing the url somehow, in order to confirm it works and thus demonstrate the app launch as a proof of concept for an app

Comment: OK, well to answer those, a) Yes it is possible using the same URL-handling as you currently do for SMSes, you just need to embed the link in your MMS, and b) you should be able to just type out the link and embed it in an MMS using either an online service or a phone.