# how to send a link in SMS message?

Tags: android

I want to send a link for `www.google.com` in sms, but I want that its shows only "Google".
when user click on "Google" its link `www.google.com` should be open. How can I do that?

Comment: I think that it's not possible. In SMS you can only sent plain text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot, SMS messages aren't composed in HTML, and don't support the concept of hyperlinks. Why don't you just send a link to http://www.google.com and let the phone figure out what to do with it? In the worst case the receiving user would have to open the message in edit mode, copy & paste the URL into the web browser.

Comment: according to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368348/internal-hyperlinks-in-a-mms/368500#368500 - MMS message is WAP/WML document, so I believe you can

Answer (score 0):

Now, You can using google  shortlink api and then send the link as a text in the share intent . And also google app invite. And Firebase app invite too.